# Validating Optional Field in WTForms

Tags: wtforms, flask-wtforms

In my user form I want to keep the 'email' field optional, but if email is mentioned, in that case my custom validator should work. I expected the following code to work. But unfortunately it's not working:

```
class AddUserForm(Form):
    email = TextField('Email ID', [validators.Optional(strip_whitespace=True)])

    @staticmethod 
    validate_email(form, field):
        if field.data is not None:
            if not is_valid_email_id_custom_function(field.data): 
                raise ValidationError('please enter a valid email id')
```

I want the following effect:

- If email field is blank, do nothing, it's ok to have it blank.
- but if email field has some data then, validate whether it is acceptable or not.

If I am declaring the email field to be optional, then validation is completely skipped. I have workaround for this, but is there any idiomatic and direct way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're defining `validate_email` as a `@staticmethod`. in-line validators are not designed to be done as a static method, but rather an instance method.  Simply remove that decorator and your validator should work whenever email is provided.